# A proof of a Proposition by Hurwitz

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Here is a proof of a Theorem by Hurwitz. (Source: [G. De Marco, Selected topic in Complex Analysis.](http://www.math.unipd.it/~pietro/doc/Complex_Analysis/De%20Marco%20-%20Selected%20topics%20of%20Complex%20Analysis2012.pdf))

[image]

(In these notes, $B(c,r]$ means the *closed* ball in $\mathbb{C}$ centered in $c\in\mathbb{C}$ and with radius $r\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, while $B(c,r[$ stands for the *open* ball centered in $c$ and with radius $r$). As you might guess, I can not derive the red-boxed inequality. I am sure it is a matter of playing around with other inequalities, but I can not get it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lvert f_n(c)\rvert = \lvert f_n(c) - f(c)\rvert \leqslant \frac{\mu}{3} < \frac{2\mu}{3} \leqslant \mu - \sup_{\lvert z-c\rvert = r}\lvert f_n(z)- f(z)\rvert\leqslant \inf_{\lvert z-c\rvert = r} \left(\lvert f(z)\rvert - \lvert f_n(z)-f(z)\rvert\right).$$

$\lvert f_n(c)\rvert \leqslant \mu/3$ because the distance between $f$ and $f_n$ is at most $\mu/3$ on the closed disk. For the same reason, on the boundary, you have $\lvert f_n(z)\rvert \geqslant \lvert f(z)\rvert - \lvert f_n(z)-f(z)\rvert \geqslant \lvert f(z)\rvert - \mu/3$. But since $\lvert f(z)\rvert \geqslant \mu$ on the boundary, you must have $\lvert f_n(z)\rvert \geqslant 2\mu/3$.

Comment: Ah, I see, that is right; it was simple, after all! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a different approach, here is a proof of the first fact using Rouché's theorem. Suppose $f(a)=0$, pick a ball $B$ around $a$ such that $f$ has no zeros on the closure of $B$ except for $a$. Pick $\epsilon<min|f(z)||_{\partial B}$. Then, for some large $n$, $|f_n(z)-2f(z)|=|(f_n(z)-f(z))+(-f(z))|\leq|f_n(z)-f(z)|+|f(z)|<\epsilon+|f(z)|$. If we restrict ourselves to the boundary, $\epsilon+|f(z)|<2|f(z)|=|2f(z)|$. Thus, $2f$ dominates $f_n-2f$ on the boundary in modulus. By Rouché's Theorem, $2f$ and $2f+f_n-2f=f_n$ have the same number of zeros inside the ball, but the latter has none while the former has one.